# 2 improprer integrals:converge or diverge

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Could you help me understand the correct way to see the behavior of these 2 integrals?

$$\int_{0}^{π/2}  \frac  {dx}{\tan(x)} $$

In 0: 1/tan(x) ~ 1/x   (diverge)

In π/2: is it right to use a direct substitution? Like 1/tan(π/2)=number (converge)

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {dx}{ \log{(x-x^2)} }$$

In 0:  ~ 1/logx

In1: I don't know

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_{0}^{π/2}  \frac  {dx}{\tan(x)}=\int_{0}^{π/4}  \frac  {dx}{\tan(x)}+\int_{π/4}^{π/2}  \cot x\,dx$$

and the first integral diverges for limit comparison with $\frac1x$.

Note that the second part converges but it is not influent on the result. For the divergence it suffices to note that the first diverges.

For the second note that for $x\to 0^+$ and for $x\to 1^-$

$$\frac {1}{ \log{(x-x^2)}}\to 0$$

thus the integral converges (since the integrand is continuos and bounded on the interval).

Comment: Int 1/tan x dx = ln abs(sin x) + c.     So ln(1)= 0 and the integral converges. Is this a correct proof for the π/2 situation?

Comment: @Errebie for the first we have problem only at 0 and as you stated it idverges

Comment: Oh gosh you're right! In 1 there's no problem! But for the second one, the interval of existence is (0,1) and not [0,1], so how is it possible to immediately state that converges?

Comment: Yes exactly, remember that you can accept the answer if it has resolved the OP, more details here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: But is it why the function has a finite number of discontinuities? In this case at the two bounds of the interval ?

Comment: Remember that improper integrals are defined as limit.

Comment: So you simply made a direct substitution with 0 and 1 to see that? Which is 1/log(0) in both cases. So it is 1/∞= 0. My problem is that I don't know when it is lecit to do a direct substitution to establish the convergence/diverg. Or using the asymptotic or the comparison method

Comment: I wiil add something asap

Comment: Now I understand. Since it is continuous over (a,b), then if it is bounded over [a,b] is integrable. This is why we can use a direct substitution.[ f(a)=0 and f(b)=0]. But in the other cases, to check if something  converges or not, if it is not calculable, we have to use the asymptotic or the comparison methods. Am I right?

Comment: In the first case the integral diverges by limit comparison test with 1/x. In the second thr integrand is continuous and bounded in the domain thus the integral has a finite value. The value of the function at the bound of the interval ar not important for improper integrals since the bound is reached to the limit. As a similar example consider $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$.